# SQLite C++ 'database is locked' when multiple processes access db in readonly mode

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite

I have an sqlite database that **doesn't change**.

**Multiple** processes that open a database connection each in **SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY** mode using sqlite3_open_v2. Each process is single threaded

The connections are made from an MSVC project using the official [C/C++ Interface](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html)'s single amalgamated C source file.

According to the SQLite FAQ [multiple processes running SELECTs is fine](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)

Each process after opening the database creates 4 prepared **SELECT** statements each with 2 bindable values.

Over the course of the execution the statements (one at a time) have the following called on them repeatedly as required

- sqlite3_bind_int
- sqlite3_bind_int
- sqlite3_step (while SQLITE_ROW is returned)
- sqlite3_column_int (while there was a row)
- sqlite3_reset

The prepared statements are reused so finalize isn't called on each of them until near the end of the program. Finally the database is closed at the very end of execution.

**The problem is** any of these operations can fail with **error code = 5: 'database is locked'**

Error code 5 is [SQLITE_BUSY](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#busy)  and the website states that

> "indicates a conflict with a separate database connection, probably in a separate process"

The rest of the internet seems to agree that multiple READONLY connections is fine. I've gone over and over the source and can't see that anything is wrong (I can't post it here sadly, I know, not helpful)

So I'm turning it to you guys, what could I possibly be missing?

**EDIT 1**:
Database is on a local drive, File system is NTFS, OS is Windows 7.

**EDIT 2**:
Wrapping all sqlite3 calls in infinite loops that check if SQLITE_BUSY was returned and then remake the call alleviates the problem. I don't consider this a fix but if that truly is the right thing to do then I'll do that.

Comment: Before opening the database, try calling `sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED)` and see what happens.

Comment: Alternatively, do `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX` in your `sqlite3_open`.

Comment: Are you using LinQ ?

Comment: QLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX doesn't help at all. 
the source desfines SQLITE_THREADSAFE 1 so sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED)  won't make any difference, 1 is serialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the working answer I have used is to wrap all the calls to sqlite in functions that loop that function while SQLITE_BUSY is returned. There doesn't seem to be a simple alternative.

```
const int bindInt(sqlite3_stmt* stmt, int parameterIndex, int value)
{
    int ret;
    do
        ret = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, parameterIndex, value);
    while (ret == SQLITE_BUSY)
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You're hammering the database constantly until you don't get a SQLITE_BUSY so I suspect that you might see a huge spike in CPU usage. Is that the case? If so adding a very small sleep (say 1 ms) may help things.

Comment: Considered it but I added a counter and in my testing didn't see anything retry more than once. Good suggestion though, will do some more testing.

Comment: This may be the valid way of doing it since after reading this link: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24340/can-i-use-sqlite-to-share-data-among-different-applications It says:  "When any process wants to write, it must lock the entire database file for the duration of its update. But that normally only takes a few milliseconds. Other processes just wait on the writer to finish then continue about their business." To be safe, probably the "other process" should also have an internal timeout to indicate that the database is not responding.

Comment: There's no writing in my case though. Only multiple processes reading.

Comment: So I only recently found this thing, haven't managed to make it work though https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_busy_handler